# what would i do if my default mainActivity.java is error in Android studio?

Tags: java, android

when ever i create a new project in android studio is showing an error message both the xml file and .java file when i build it showing me 7 error in the mainActivity and 1 error in the xml file[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L27Ad.jpg)

I've tried to refresh both the file but all in vein

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's problem with your gradle, some files is't downloaded correctly.
connect your laptop to wifi when creating a new project, it download some missing gradle file and it will be fix.

If the specified plugin version has not been downloaded, Gradle downloads it the next time you build your project or click **File > Sync Project with Gradle Files** from the Android Studio menu bar.

Read about gradle

https://gradle.org/

https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin